# Как проверить, что строка не содержит кириллицу и спецсимволы при помощи регулярного выражения?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Мне надо валидировать пароль и логин.

Строка может содержать латинские буквы, цифры и знак `_`

Сейчас мой код не проверяет на знаки `$%#&?` и др.

Как разрешить только знак `_` и вернуть `false` если есть другие знаки?

```java
private static boolean isValidPasswordAndLogin(String password) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*[_]*(?=\\S+$).{8,}");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(password);

    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("[а-яёА-ЯЁ]+");
    Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(password);

    if (matcher.find() && !matcher2.find()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: если правильно понял, то достаточно `\w{8,}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если известно, что допустимые символы включают только цифры,  английские буквы и подчёркивание, следует использовать класс символов `\w` и регулярное выражение для диапазона таких символов с минимальной длиной: `str.matches("\\w{8,}")`:

```java
private static boolean isValidPasswordAndLogin(String password) {
    return password.matches("\\w{8,}");
}
```

Тесты:

```java
for (String p : new String[]{"acb_123!", "abc-defgh", "123%xxyyzz", "2345_6758$", "$abcdefgh"}) {
    System.out.println(p + " isValid? " + isValidPasswordAndLogin(p));
}
```

Проверка НЕ пропускает символы `!%$`:

```
acb_123! isValid? false
abc-defgh isValid? false
123%xxyyzz isValid? false
2345_6758$ isValid? false
$abcdefgh isValid? false
```

Comment: Пропускает знаки %$!

Comment: Все разобрался. добавил в конце $ и все заработал 
"\\w{8,}$"

Comment: Никакого добавления `$` (признака конца строки) в регулярке _в моём решении_ не надо, так как `String::matches` и без того проверяет всю строку целиком (аналогично `Matcher:::matches`).  А вот при использовании `Matcher::find` этот якорь может понадобиться.